# Initializing default value of javafx's TextField using spring boot @Configuraion and @Value

Tags: java, spring, javafx

Orignially I have a simple spring boot project, with a config file called DemoConfig.java, shown as below:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class DemoConfig
{
    @Value("${deviceName}")
    private String deviceName;

    @Value("${platformName}")
    private String platformName;

    @Value("${platformVersion}")
    private String platformVersion;

    @Value("${appPackage}")
    private String appPackage;

    @Value("${appActivity}")
    private String appActivity;
```

Now I want to apply javafx onto my project, somehow start a configuration page for users to configure these values. So I have this DemoController.java to serve as the fx:controller.

```
@Component
public class DemoController
{
    @Resource
    private DemoConfig demoConfig;

    public TextField platformName = new TextField(demoConfig.getPlatformName());

    public TextField platformVersion = new TextField(demoConfig.getPlatformVersion());

    public TextField deviceName = new TextField(demoConfig.getDeviceName());

    public TextField appActivity = new TextField(demoConfig.getAppActivity());

    public TextField appPackage = new TextField(demoConfig.getAppPackage());

}
```

Now I end up with : The initialization of DemoController will fail because DemoConfig hasn't been injected as a bean yet, I am kinda confused as to how to combine the Controller with my Configuration class.
My goal is simple, just to initialize the Controller's textfield with the values of bean DemoConfig.
Any ideas would help! Thanks!

Comment: If this is the controller for an FXML file, you should not be instantiating the text fields at all. If they are declared in the FXML file, the `FXMLLoader` will instantiate them and inject them into the controller. Just set the text in the controller’s `initialize()` method; your dependencies will have been injected when that is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I did not take FXML into account for my answer. All credits go to James_D for valid comment after answer was already accepted.

### When using FXML (Prefered)

From the comments:

> If this is the controller for an FXML file, you should not be
>   instantiating the text fields at all. If they are declared in the FXML
>   file, the FXMLLoader will instantiate them and inject them into the
>   controller. Just set the text in the controller’s initialize() method;
>   your dependencies will have been injected when that is called. –
>   James_D

### Not taking into account FXML

Use @PostConstruct: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-postconstruct-predestroy
This should insure your bean is injected (if there are no other issues).

Place all your textfield initializations in the postconstruct:

```
@Component
public class DemoController
{
    @Autowire
    private DemoConfig demoConfig;

    public TextField platformName;

    public TextField platformVersion;

    public TextField deviceName;

    public TextField appActivity;

    public TextField appPackage;


    @PostConstruct
    private void postConstruct() {
        platformName = new TextField(demoConfig.getPlatformName());

        platformVersion = new TextField(demoConfig.getPlatformVersion());

        deviceName = new TextField(demoConfig.getDeviceName());

        appActivity = new TextField(demoConfig.getAppActivity());

        appPackage = new TextField(demoConfig.getAppPackage());
    }
```

}

Comment: This is not correct. If this is supposed to be used as a controller for an associated FXML file, the `FXMLLoader` will instantiate the text fields and inject them into the controller. The `@PostConstruct` method here is completely redundant; if this is set up correctly, the text fields constructed in that method will immediately be replaced with new ones when the FXML file is loaded.

Comment: @James_D is right, `@PostConstruct` not needed here.

Comment: @AbinashGhosh Moreover, *initializing the text fields* is not needed here, anywhere in the class.

Comment: Basically, this is an [x-y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). My best guess here is that something is wrong in the FXML file, which is causing null pointer exceptions when the OP tries to set the text on the text fields. Instead of asking how to fix that problem, they've attempted to instantiate the text fields in the controller (which is incorrect) and are now asking questions about the incorrect solution, instead of asking questions to address the original problem (which we don't have enough information to answer).

Comment: FXML was not mentioned anywere in his question. As he already accepted it, i can't remove the answer anymore. I'll add your comment James.

Comment: The question is very poorly written. However, the OP does explicitly state that the controller class is referenced by a `fx:controller` attribute, which clearly indicates that it is intended to be a controller for an FXML file.

Comment: Must have missed that originally. You are right James, sorry about that.